# Contentful Only Showing 40/80 Entries on NextJS App

Tags: pagination, vercel, next.js13, contentful, contentful-management

I'm using Contentful as my CMS and NextJS on Vercel to display the content.

I'm trying to figure out how to pull unpaginated entries from Contentful. I set the `limit` to 100, but I'm still only getting 40 entries.

Can someone explain how to do pagination with Contentful and also pull unpaginated entries? Thanks.

Here's my repo:
https://github.com/davinaleong/proj-laugh-and-be-blessed-next

Comment: Hey, did you check this article: https://www.contentful.com/blog/paginating-contentful-blogposts-with-nextjs-graphql-api/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the article. Will check it out!

Comment: Haha... I realized the issue was not all the content matched the query criteria...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post my answer to help others.

The issue was with my query. Only 40 entries matched the query I was sending to Contentful. After correcting the entries on Contentful, I was able to query all 80+ entries.

So... remember to check both your query and your data on Contentful!